# How to fix incorrect (small) view on my main storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

So In my main storyboard one of my view controllers view is smaller than it should be, making that part of the UIView untouchable to the users... I don't know if its a tool bar or some weird inherited view from the previous view controller as it does have a relationship to the previous view controller

tried removing tool bar, I even put my tableview over top of the view making it bigger, but it is unusable on the iPhone after the build

[image: Image of issue]

I just need it removed, its a grey bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that gray is being passed over to your present view controller, I would remove the segue to check if the view updates its constraints, if so remove the previous view controller and embed it to the previous to remove the bar